# iCloud storage and backups

Tags: icloud, backup

My icloud account kept telling me it was nearly full. I had only 1 back up listed on my iphone (i don't have a mac etc) and the same on the dashboard on my laptop. I deleted the 4.9gb backup (nothing important- full of photos and videos already saved elsewhere) and now i have the full free 5gb listed in my storage. Does this mean my iCloud storage is now completely empty?

Answer (score 1):

By default, iCloud storage is 5GB large. So if you're saying under

- Settings > iCloud > Storage

you're seeing 5GB available, then yes your iCloud storage's been emptied.